# доставка файлов в SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Есть защищенная ссылка на папку в SharePoint. Доступ к папке по ссылке предоставлен нескольким пользователям. После переходе по ссылке запрашивает пользователя, после ввода пользователя отправляет на почту код подтверждения, если у него есть доступ. Необходимо синхронизировать эту папку с ПК или как-то по другому автоматизировать доставку туда файлов.

Comment: Скорее всего подойдут топорные способы - автоматизация работы с браузером , или писать свой http клиент. Кто-нибудь что-то подобное делал?

Comment: Делал, но вам кроме шарика, понадобится язык программирования... и тут вариантов немного: javascript или c#.

Comment: Никак не могу найти примеры. Может подскажите какой-нибудь урок?

Comment: для начала посмотрите: [stackoverflov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint), [пример для VB](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms454491(v%3Doffice.14)), [Вариант на шарпе](http://www.ktskumar.com/2009/03/upload-document-from-local-machine-to-sharepoint-library/).